# Take snapshot from webcam on website

Tags: html5-video, webcam, snapshot

I try to take snapshot from webcam on web browser. When I use this code below it works on mobile (Google Chrome on Android), but not on Google Chrome on Desktop. The video is not displayed. I get an error name: `TrackStartError` or `DevicesNotFoundError`. It was tested with external USB webcam.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Display Webcam Stream</title>
    <style>
        #container {
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 480px;
        }

        video, img {
            max-width: 100%;
            background-color: #f2f3f5;
        }

        video {
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <video autoplay></video>
</div>
<script>
    var video = document.querySelector('video'), canvas;


    function takeSnapshot() {
        var img = document.querySelector('img') || document.createElement('img');
        var context;
        var width = video.offsetWidth, height = video.offsetHeight;

        canvas = canvas || document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;

        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

        img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }

    if (navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
        navigator.mediaDevices = {};
    }

    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === undefined) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function (constraints) {

            var getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

            if (!getUserMedia) {
                return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser'));
            }

            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
            });
        }
    }

    var constraints = {audio: false, video: {width: 640, height: 480}};
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
            .then(function (stream) {
                if ("srcObject" in video) {
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                } else {
                    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                }

                video.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
                    video.play();
                };

                video.addEventListener('click', takeSnapshot);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
            });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm out of any options :(
What I'm doing wrong? It should work on most used desktop web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

**Most probably your webcam or webcam drivers are not functioning correctly.**

That's what the 2 errors that you're getting point to:

- `DevicesNotFoundError` is a non spec error thrown by Chrome when you’re requesting a video track (through constraints) but a webcam is missing. The Firefox/spec equivalent is `NotFoundError`.
- `TrackStartError` is a non spec error thrown by Chrome (on Windows) when the webcam is already in use by another app. The Firefox/spec equivalent is  `NotReadableError`. The [MDN description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) points to other causes as well:

  > Although the user granted permission to use the matching devices, a hardware error occurred at the operating system, browser, or Web page level which prevented access to the device

Source: [Common getUserMedia() Errors](https://blog.addpipe.com/common-getusermedia-errors/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (just work for videos):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="stuff, to, help, search, engines, not" name="keywords">
<meta content="What this page is about." name="description">
<meta content="Display Webcam Stream" name="title">
<title>Display Webcam Stream</title>

<style>
#container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    border: 10px #333 solid;
}
#videoElement {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    background-color: #666;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">

    </video>
</div>
<script>
 var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {       
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
  .then(function(stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
  })
  .catch(function(err0r) {
    console.log("Something went wrong!");
  });
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm